# Why in 33:56 Allah SWT, instead of himself saying directly, is ordering to the holy Prophet SAW to tell the women of the believers?

Tags: quran, tafseer

Why in [33:56](https://legacy.quran.com/33/59) Allah SWT, instead of himself **telling it directly (meaning addressing to us)**, is ordering to the holy Prophet SAW to tell the women of the believers to bring down over themselves [part] of their outer garments?

**Does this mean that Allah SWT wants this (bringing down over themselves [part] of their outer garments) to be a Sunnah rather than Fard?**

[The verse](https://legacy.quran.com/33/59):

> O Prophet, **tell** your wives and your daughters and **the women of
>   the believers to bring down over themselves [part] of their outer
>   garments**. That is more suitable that they will be known and not be
>   abused. And ever is Allah Forgiving and Merciful.

Comment: If it was just a sunnah than Why is God talking about forgiveness at the end of the verse ?

Answer (score 1):

“And as for women past childbearing who do not expect wedlock, it is no sin on them if they discard their (outer) clothing in such a way as not to show their adornment. But to refrain (i.e. not to discard their outer clothing) is better for them. And Allaah is All‑Hearer, All‑Knower”

[al-Noor 24:60]

If Allah mentions it's no sin on older women, that means it IS a sin on younger women, otherwise there would be no reason to mention this. And yes, ALLAH is saying this directly.
So you have to look elsewhere. We can only pick "flaws" in Sharia if we close our eyes. Hijab is a Fard.

Comment: I downvoted your answer as I didn't like the analogy you used. It looks not proper to me to compare God and His Prophet with Husband and wife. The holy Prophet SAW is servant or slave of God while husband and wife are partners in life :). It would be good if you used another analogy. Maybe you could use an example of a president and a CEO of company and an employee in the company

Answer (score 1):

Allah always send Messengers and Prophets to convey his message, he never talk directly to any men, see the Quran verse 51 of ayah 'Ash-Shura' 42:

https://quran.com/42/51

> And it is not for any human being that Allah should speak to him
>   except by revelation or from behind a partition or that He sends a
>   messenger to reveal, by His permission, what He wills. Indeed, He is
>   Most High and Wise.

Comment: The question is not about how we get revelation.

Comment: That's what Surah says, Allah don't talk to people directly. If he will tell you something, can you convey that to the entire people, and who will believe you? and many others will start spreading fake message on the name of religion. Do you have better reason?